# Spark Write csv - timestamp format issue

Tags: csv, apache-spark, timestamp

I am having timestamp format in hive tables upto 6 mill sec, while writing spark CSV format - it does not let me write more than 3 mill sec.

> 1) source format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.SSSSSS"
>   2) csv format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.SSS"

- even after specifying the format upto 6 SSSSSS millisecs in the write CSV, does not work.

  ```
  DF.write.
  option("sep","~").
  option("quoteAll", "true").
  option("timestampFormat","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
  ```

  - does not work?

Does someone know any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Option "timestampFormat" is not specified in documentation:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv .
Maybe, "dateFormat" can be used with the same value.

As workaround, timestamp can be converted into string manually before saving.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet that worked for me.

I needed a 'T' character in there, and no seconds or microseconds.  The **timestampFormat** option did work for this.

```
DF.write
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
```

Such as `2017-02-20T06:53`

If you substitute a space for 'T' then you get this:

```
DF.write
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
```

Such as `2017-02-20 06:53`